# Nested webrequest

Tags: json, powershell, webrequest

Pulling related artists information from the last.fm api.  When I input an artist, the webrequest returns 100 artists that are similar.  What I want to do (without creating an infinite loop) is to go one more level and pull the related artists of those artists and append it to the same file.

For example, input Parachute

Output:  Andy Grammer, Hot Chelle Rae, Jon McLaughlin, ....

I want to nest the same command to get the related artists for Andy Grammer, append it to the file, then related artists for Hot Chelle Rae, then append it to the file ....

Code so far is:

```
$bands_list =@('parachute')
foreach ($band in $bands_list){$url1="http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=$band&api_key=(my api key)&format=json"
    Invoke-WebRequest $url1 |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    select -expand similarartists |
    select -expand artist |
    select name|
    convertto-csv |
    ForEach-Object{Write-Output "$band,$_"} >similarartistmatch.txt
   }
```

This process gives me around 100 related artists to the original artist.  I use the {Write-Output "$band,$_"} so in each line I get the original artists in the first column, then the related artist in the second column (so I can show that relationship).  In the end, I would expect one file that has 10000 items in it.

Seems easy, but I dont want to run into an infinite loop.  I only want to go two levels deep:  original artist, related artist, related artist's related artist.

Comment: To avoid the infinite loop, you have to maintain and check against a list of the artists that you already processed.

Comment: Everytime the query runs for one artist, it returns 100 artists.  I'm ok with 10,000 (1 original x (100 orig. related artists) x (100 related artist's related artist).  Its not about duplicating what already has been processed.  Its more about not wanting it to do 1X100x100x100x100......